# get the id of the image from another html file using javascript

Tags: javascript

I using iframe for displaying a image. Here is my code.

index.html

```
<html>
 <head>
    <title>Center</title
    <script type="text/javascript">
            function sample(id){
               var frameht=document.getElementById("ifrm").style.height;
               var framewd=document.getElementById("ifrm").style.width;
           }
    </script>
 </head>
 <body>
    <iframe style="width:700px;height:600px;" src="test.html" id="ifrm" onload="javascript:sample(this.id);"></iframe>
 </body>
</html>
```

test.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Center</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="14.jpg" id="img1" onload="javascript:sample();"/>
</body>
</html>
```

I want the id of the image in index.html. Is it possible to get? Any one can help? Please!

Answer (score 2):

```
document.getElementById('ifrm').contentWindow.document.getElementById('img1');
```

this should work

```
img = document.getElementById('ifrm').contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName('img');
```

img[0].id to get the dinamically id

Comment: Image ID and tag is dynamically creating. I just gave as static for sample. Can you please tell at which file i call this function?

Comment: I dont know where you want to use it, cant tell exactly, a onclick maybe? About the dinamically img, you can search the img using getElementsByTagName('img') add it to a variable and make a for to select it or just use variable[0] to get the first element found on getElementsByTagName('img').

Answer (score 2):

First get iframe.

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('ifrm');
```

**Get access to elements of iframe.**

```
var frameDoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
```

Then, get id by tagname. In our case img.

```
var el = frameDoc.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].id;
```

Here is an example without iframe, to give you an idea how to get id of element after:
http://jsfiddle.net/nukec/eymq2/

Answer (score 1):

Insted of id use name and try this..

```
<script>
window.frames["fName"].document.getElementById("img1");
</script>

<iframe style="width:700px;height:600px;" src="test.htm" id="ifrm" name="fName" onload="javascript:sample(this.id);"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use jQuery

```
var imageObj= $('#myiframe').contents().find('img');
var imgId=$(imageObj).attr("id");
```